# How to know reactors all process are completed

Tags: python, twisted

I am new to twisted and python, I am reading twisted python.

registering call

```
reactor.callLater(_interval, self.count, *args)
```

I have created Countdown class and it contains count function, I am calling it three time

```
reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown().count, 1)
reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown().count, 2)
reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown().count, 3)
```

with different time interval, and I need to stop reactor when all call is finished. So is in twisted API have some method to know all call is completed.

My Code is

```
class Countdown(object):

    counter = 5

    def count(self, *args):
    _interval = args[0]
        name = args[1]
        if self.counter == 0 and name == "Third Call":
            reactor.stop()
        elif self.counter == 0:
        print name, " Finished..!"
        else:
            print self.counter, '...'
            self.counter -= 1
            reactor.callLater(_interval, self.count, *args)

from twisted.internet import reactor

reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown().count, 1, "First Call")
reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown().count, 2, "Second Call")
reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown().count, 3, "Third Call")

print 'Start!'
reactor.run()
print 'Stop!'
```

Now I am using 
    if self.counter == 0 and name == "Third Call":
to prevent my all counter process is finished. So now I need to know, is there in twisted have any built in method to know all call is finished or my all counter call is finished.

Comment: This is a bit confusing.  Are you using `callLater` or `callWhenRunning`?  Both?  You want to know when all four calls have happened?  Or when one in particular has happened?

Comment: sorry for my bad english. I have updated code on question description please let you review it and suggest me best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted has an API for working with a list of events: DeferredList http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#auto8

Here is a small example how this might work:

```
from twisted.internet import defer 
from twisted.internet import reactor


def delayedFunction(dF):
    print('I was called')
    dF.success(True)

class Counter(object):
    def timeOffsetExecute(self,delay):
        dF = defer.Deferred()
        reactor.callLater(delay,delayedFunction,dF)
        return dF

def onAllResult(val):
    print 'All delayed functions called'
    reactor.stop()

cp = Counter()

dl = defer.DeferredList([cp.timeOffsetExecute(1), cp.timeOffsetExecute(3), cp.timeOffsetExecute(9)], consumeErrors=True)
dl.addCallback(onAllResult)

reactor.run()
```

Comment: mind you - I have no python or twisted on the machine I am posting from, so this might be broken. But the idea is as above.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on the same exercise from [Twisted Introduction](http://krondo.com/?p=1333) and found that solution is pretty straightforward (assuming it should be solved without using deferreds) with use of shared static variable to count running instances:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Countdown(object):

    running = 0

    def __init__(self, value, delay=1):
        self.delay = delay
        self.counter = value
        Countdown.running += 1

    def __call__(self):
        if self.counter == 0:
            Countdown.running -= 1
            if Countdown.running == 0:
                reactor.stop()
        else:
            print self.counter, '...'
            self.counter -= 1
            reactor.callLater(self.delay, self)

reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown(10, 0.5))
reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown(5, 2))
reactor.callWhenRunning(Countdown(7, 1.5))

print 'Start!'
reactor.run()
print 'Stop!'
```

Answer (score 0):

My take:

```
class Countdown(object):

counter1 = 5
counter2 = 20
counter3 = 50

def count1(self):
    if self.counter1 == 0 and self.counter2 == 0 and self.counter3 == 0:
        reactor.stop()
    elif self.counter1 > 0:
        print self.counter1, '... process',1
        self.counter1 -= 1
        reactor.callLater(0.1, self.count1)

def count2(self):
    if self.counter1 == 0 and self.counter2 == 0 and self.counter3 == 0:
        reactor.stop()
    elif self.counter2 > 0:
        print self.counter2, '... process',2
        self.counter2 -= 1.25
        reactor.callLater(0.12, self.count2)

def count3(self):
    if self.counter1 == 0 and self.counter2 == 0 and self.counter3 == 0:
        reactor.stop()
    elif self.counter3 > 0:
        print self.counter3, '... process',3
        self.counter3 -= 12.5
        reactor.callLater(0.2345, self.count3)

from twisted.internet import reactor

obj = Countdown()
reactor.callWhenRunning(obj.count1)
reactor.callWhenRunning(obj.count2)
reactor.callWhenRunning(obj.count3)

print 'Start!'
reactor.run()
print 'Stop!'
```

Here I have not used any deferred method solution.